# Heuristic completion: outcome state is rolled back;

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am using GORM tool to map domains objects with database and below is code:

```
public BatchJobMetaData getBatchJobMetaDataById(Integer batchJobMetaDataId){
    return BatchJobMetaData.get(batchJobMetaDataId)     
}
```

I am getting ''''Heuristic completion: outcome state is rolled back;''' exception

Full Exception track:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.HeuristicCompletionException: Heuristic completion: outcome state is rolled back; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager.commit(ChainedTransactionManager.java:174)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:478)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:272)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
        at com.cscglobal.dbstools.brandreports.service.PortfolioStrategyService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2dc9d6ea.getPortfolioStrategInput(<generated>)
        at com.cscglobal.dbstools.brandreports.service.PortfolioStrategyService$getPortfolioStrategInput$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at com.cscglobal.dbstools.batch.brandreports.portfoliostrategy.PortfolioStrategyListItemReader.beforeStep(PortfolioStrategyListItemReader.groovy:31)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionSynchronization.getCurrentSession(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:51)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionSynchronization.beforeCommit(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:85)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:95)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:928)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:740)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.transaction.MultiTransactionStatus.commit(MultiTransactionStatus.java:73)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager.commit(ChainedTransactionManager.java:147)
```

I have tried using withSession to solve but could solve the issue:

```
public BatchJobMetaData getBatchJobMetaDataById(Integer batchJobMetaDataId){
    BatchJobMetaData batchJobMetaData = new BatchJobMetaData();
    BatchJobMetaData.withSession{
        batchJobMetaData = BatchJobMetaData.get(batchJobMetaDataId)     
    }
    return batchJobMetaData
}
```

I have also used this:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public BatchJobMetaData getBatchJobMetaDataById(Integer batchJobMetaDataId){
    return BatchJobMetaData.get(batchJobMetaDataId)     
}
```

I have also used this:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public BatchJobMetaData getBatchJobMetaDataById(Integer batchJobMetaDataId){
    return BatchJobMetaData.get(batchJobMetaDataId)     
}
```

But still exception occurring. Could you please help me with this exception:

Answer (score 1):

*Heuristic completion and rollback* can be caused by a **failing MySQL query** that rolls back a transaction. See your logs for details. Sometimes you can see you query working on one server and failing on another. In this case try comparing MYSQL modes and removing some syntax changing modes like **"ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY"**, for example.

To set the SQL mode at server startup, use the `--sql-mode="modes"` option on the command line, or `sql-mode="modes"` in an option file such as `my.cnf`.

To change the SQL mode at runtime, set the global or session sql_mode system variable using a SET statement:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'modes';
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'modes';

# Adding a mode to sql_mode:
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));

# Removing a mode from sql_mode:
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT CONCAT(@@sql_mode,',ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have got the answer:

Using withTransction is the solution.

```
public BatchJobMetaData getBatchJobMetaDataById(Integer batchJobMetaDataId){
        BatchJobMetaData batchJobMetaData = new BatchJobMetaData()
        BatchJobMetaData.withTransaction { status ->
            batchJobMetaData = BatchJobMetaData.get(batchJobMetaDataId)
         }
        return batchJobMetaData 
    }
```